# Separation of variables for a function of 3 variables $V(x, y, z)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, differential-equations

I'm trying to find the solutions for $V(x,y,z)$ by separation of variables.

Is it correct to say:

$$\frac{1}{X}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2} + \frac{1}{Y}\frac{d^2y}{dy^2} + \frac{1}{Z}\frac{d^2z}{dz^2} = 0$$

thus

$$\frac{1}{X}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2} = K_1$$
$$\frac{1}{Y}\frac{d^2y}{dy^2} = K_2$$
$$\frac{1}{Z}\frac{d^2z}{dz^2} = -K_1 - K_2 = K_3$$

From what I see in my book I think the solutions are as follows, but I'm not sure I understand why.

$$X(x) = A \cos(kx) + B\sin(kx)$$

$$Y(y) = C \cos(ky) + D\sin(ky)$$

$$Z(z) = Ee^{\sqrt{(k^2+l^2)}z} + Fe^{-\sqrt{(k^2+l^2)}z}$$

Comment: Seems maybe like a question for [Math SE](http://maths.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I wasn't sure. Basically, it's a physics question, but I don't understand that part. If you like, I found the question with the solution [here](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/a-cubical-box-sides-of-lenght-a-consists-of-five-metal-plates-which-are-welded-together-and-grounded/), but like in my book there's not a lot of explanation about the solutions.

Comment: what kind of physics is this an equation for?

Comment: I have to find the potential inside a box. 5 sides grounded and the top is held at constant potential $V_0$

Comment: are you sure it isn't? $$X(x) = A cos(kx) + Bsin(kx)$$

$$Y(y) = C cos(ly) + Dsin(ly)$$

$$Z(z) = Ee^{i\sqrt(k^2+l^2)z} + Fe^{-i\sqrt(k^2+l^2)z}$$ what you've written doesn't look right to me

Comment: I'm not sure, but even [here](http://www.physics.sfsu.edu/~lea/courses/ugrad/360notes7.PDF)

The solution don't have i and -i.

Comment: ok. sometimes you can use imaginary numbers and then just ignore the imaginary part. in physics.

Comment: @epselonzero but i don't see how you are going to get those oscillations without i. If X oscillates then z must oscillate by symmetry. but i don't know. i could be wrong.

Comment: @ExpertNonexpert:  I don't think you're right.  In general, when you separate variables in rectangular coordinates, you end up with one function in exponentials and the other two in sinusoids.  The reason your symmetry argument fails is that you're looking for a solution to a problem with asymmetric boundary conditions in the first place (i.e., the potential on the boundaries of constant $x$ is different from the potential on the boundaries of constant $z$.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert but i've already explicitly shown that this is a solution below.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert ok. i see what you are saying. but, on the other hand, he didn't mention B.C.s. I would like to know them and see if my basic Euler's formula approach works.

Comment: @ExpertNonexpert:  Your derivation is incorrect, I'm afraid;  see my comment on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question really boils down to choosing what the constants $K_1$, $K_2$, and $K_3 = -K_1 - K_2$ are.  If $K_1$ is positive, then the solution for $x$ will be a sum of real exponentials;  if $K_1$ is negative, then the solution will be sinusoidal.

The question is then which option to choose.  This usually boils down to a careful examination of the boundary conditions.  Notably, sums of exponentials have the property that they can only be zero at one value of their argument;  but sinusoids can be zero at multiple different values of their argument.

This means that (for example) if the boundary conditions require that $X(0) = 0$ and $X(a) = 0$ for some $a \neq 0$ (i.e., we have *homogeneous* boundary conditions in $x$) then you can get this to work by picking $K_1 < 0$.  Or, which is equivalent, you can define $k$ such that $K_1 = -k^2$;  we then have $X = \cos(kx)$ or $\sin(kx)$.  The allowable values of $k$ will then be those for which the sinusoidal function vanishes at $x = a$.

Similarly, if you also have homogeneous boundary conditions in the $y$ direction, you can define $l$ so that $K_2 = - l^2$, and $Y = \cos(ly)$ (or $\sin (ly)$.)  But this then implies that $K_3 = k^2 + l^2 > 0$, and the $Z$ function is a sum of exponentials:  $Z = e^{\pm\sqrt{k^2 + l^2}z}.$

Note that you could equally well have chosen other value of $K_1$ and $K_2$ and obtained different sorts of solutions for the $X$ and $Y$ functions.  But it would have been impossible to make them satisfy homogeneous boundary conditions in the $x$ and $y$ directions.  Which constants of separation you choose to be positive and which you choose to be negative really depends on the boundary conditions in play.